# How to check if an object has a certain operator implemented?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am new with Kotlin and I am wondering if there is a method to check if a parameter object has plus operator.
For example I want complete this function:

```
fun <T: Any> T.plusWithOther(other: T): T {
    if(T has plusOperator){
        return this + other
    }
    return this
}
```

Comment: Afaik there is no way. Keep in mind that the plus operator can have arbitrary types for both the parameter and return, e.g. `operator fun String.plus(y: Int): Long`.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to query for a specific operator. However, there are extension functions for the plus and minus operators.

As an example:

```
infix fun <T> T.add(other: T): T = this + other
```

So you can use add instead of plus:

```
fun <T: Any> T.plusWithOther(other: T): T {
    if(T has addOperator){
        return this add other // or plus, minus, etc. based on what you need from the function 
    }  return this 
}
```

Comment: Why would this work? It's almost the same function in the question.

Comment: This will work because the plus operator (and any other infix operator) is actually an extension function.

So if you have the following extension function:
`infix fun <T> T.add(other: T): T = this + other`
Then it means that "this" has a method "add", which takes one argument of type "T" and returns a value of type "T". In this case, it returns a new instance of T.

Comment: The "has" query is actually just a method call to the same object. So if you have the following object:

`class Foo(val name: String) {`
    `infix fun add(other: Foo): Foo = Foo("$name & ${other.name}")`
`}`
Then "Foo" has an operator "add". It takes one argument of type "Foo" and returns a value of type "Foo". In this case, it creates a new instance of Foo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The `has` you wrote doesn't exist in Kotlin. Your code won't compile (for more than one reason).

Comment: You're right. The "has" query doesn't exist in Kotlin, but the code is correct. You are calling the same operator "add" from the extension function, so this is a method call on a generic class. If you want to declare an operator with no arguments, you must specify it as a function rather than an extension function:

`operator fun <T> T.add(other: T): T = this + other`

Comment: Then you can use "has" to check if that particular object has an operator:
`fun <T> T.plusWithOther(other: T): T {
    if(T has addOperator){
        return this add other // or plus, minus, etc. based on what you need from the function 
    }  return this 
}`

Comment: Con you write a working example in Kotlin playground and post it? https://play.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: @PJMan0300 that is not a solution, try to write your infix function into IDE and you get an error where the + is not defined.